# Application Insights getting data, but no live metrics for a worker service

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a .net6 worker service using application insights.  I can see overview data (like server request) and logged errors with Log Analytics.  However, I cannot see Live Metrics.  I get the error:

```
Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK
```

I've setup the connectionstring in appsettings, and added services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService() to Configure Services.  I belive this is correct because I am getting data in applicaiton insights, just no live metrics.

In application insight, in the End-to-end transaction details, I can see the SDK verson in il:2.21.0-429.  This matches what I have installed and shows I have connected to applicaiton insights.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this question while trying to fix this. I am using a console application with the `WorkerService` and had to use `telemetryClient.Flush();` after configuring my Application Insights for Live Metrics to work.

https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/examples/ConsoleApp/Program.cs

Answer (score -1):

> I cannot see Live Metrics

If you want to view the live metrics, you need to add the necessary packages in your application.

- I hope you are using Latest **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights** package if not try to update the latest version.
- Add **[Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService)** Package in your application to view the application telemetry data in a **Live Stream**.
- Use the latest packages and SDK in your project.
  [image]
- Still, you are facing issue you are not able get the telemetry data in Live metrics stream. Try to redeploy your application with latest packages.
- Try to Modify the filter of your **Live metrics -> Sample telemetry**
  [image]
  After I changed **Success= false** to **true** I can be able to see the results in stream
  [image]

#### Live metric Result

[image]

#### Workaround follows

I have followed the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service) and added the necessary packages to send the telemetry data into application insights. By default, if we were using **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService** package it will send the **telemetry data to Live metrics Stream**.

After added the **services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()** I can be able to see the telemetry data in a Live Metrics.

##### Result

[image]